# HTML5 SPA authentication

Tags: html, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

As of now, we have an authentication service using Spring Security OAuth2 which implements the following grant types: client_credentials and password.

To obtain a token, a client (potentially an HTML5 SPA client) would have to store the client_id and secret to obtain a bearer token with either the client_credentials or password grant type. For this case, it's not very safe as anyone the client_id and secret would live within the HTML5 apps source and anyone could obtain it.

Is there a different flow for this, other than client_credentials or password?

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, for SPA s the recommended authorization protocol is OAth with Implicit grant.

You can read a bit more about how that is implemented in Azure Active Directory (it is free) here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-dev-understanding-oauth2-implicit-grant

and here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-implicit